# What is the point of a .cpp file containing only a single #include?

Tags: c++, header, include

I am starting some work using a third party library and when building it in Visual Studio 2010, I noticed I was receiving this linker warning many times ([LNK4221](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/604bzebd.aspx)). I looked at the sources used in creating the object files that were being linked and found that all of the implementation for these is located in the header files. Interestingly, I also noticed the project included corresponding .cpp files containing **only** a #include for the header with the implementation.

I am curious - what is the point of this and why would I want to use this technique? If the .cpp files aren't adding any value to the project, why shouldn't I just remove them to get rid of the linker warnings?

I tried searching for similar questions, but didn't find anything of interest. If you know of any, please link them.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm less concerned about the warning than the technique of using .cpp files containing only a single #include.

Comment: Two possible motivations: 1 - May be considered good practice to always have `.h`/`.cpp` pairs. Maybe the author thought they would add to the `.cpp` later. 2 - A `.h` file can't be compiled into an object file, a `.cpp` file can.

Comment: OK, thanks. Those are definitely reasonable. I know that the headers are used in other places though, say for example to use with class inheritance. I had a coworker tell me that it's a valid approach when you need to create different linker objects in different places in the code, but he couldn't really give me any details or remember why exactly one might want to do that (he said he had to do it in one of our products, but I'm still looking for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this to make sure, that the header is at least in one file included at the first position. By doing so, I make sure that the header is compilable on it's own.

To convence the linker to not issue a warning, one could use an external variable with a very large variable:

```
int variable_with_a_name_that_includes_the_file_name_somehow = 42;
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but would you remove that file if you then later used the header elsewhere?

Comment: @Joe no, when it's included somewhere else, it's hard to make sure, it will so do in the future and that no one will put an include before that include.

Comment: OK, so in that case it just acts as safe-guard against misuse down the road. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Was the single `#include`d file stdafx.h? I. That case, you're dealing with [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The normal setup is for one .cpp file having "generate precompiled headers" compiler option, and the rest of the .cpp files in your project having "use pch".

Comment: No, it wasn't actually stdafx.h, but I did find references to it when I looked for answers earlier. However, this is still useful information, so thank you!